# parallel search for algorithms

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, parallel-processing

I don't get how will the redundancies be reduced on chance nodes since i think negamax is almost just similar with minimax algorithm.

Comment: I'd think parallel search would require partitioning the data you are searching into `n` blocks and then searching through each block using `n` parallel threads.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508185/parallel-search

Comment: ahh so i'm gonna use multithreading?

Answer (score 2):

At each chance node, you would create a thread to continue execution down the path your main application did not choose.  This is efficient as there is equal probability of the solution being down each path.

You have to remember that the primary execution path for the algorithim is following what it considers the best choice at each node.  Parallelising at a min max node would be wasteful because you already have 'better' choice, so continuing down the path of lesser value is less likely to yield the best result.

At a chance node, there is no 'better' choice.  Both are choices have equal probability to yield the best result, so following both at the same time would theoretically yield the solution faster than waiting for the software to follow one node down to its completion and then go back and process the other option.

Comment: wow thanks. anyway how do you do a parallel program in java? it seems it since you have to manipulate multiply processors? i'm not really adept when it comes to OS.